# sqlite count row with string equals to

Tags: android, sqlite

I've a database with column VNP containing text "G", "Y", or "R".
with this adapter I set background color correctly, but it doesn't count the row with same Letter

```
......
        vnp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vnp);
....

     adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
          public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.semaphore)
                {
                String VNP = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    if(VNP.equals("G"))
                {view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                green=green+1;}
                    if(VNP.equals("Y"))
                {view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                yellow=yellow+1;}
                    if(VNP.equals("R"))
                {view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                red=red+1;}

                vnp.setText("G: " +String.valueOf(green)+ "- Y: " +yellow+ " - R: " +red);
               return true;

          }
```